# SQL query to get the full name, email id, phone of tenants who are married and paying rent > 9000 using subqueries

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to write a query to get the full name, email id, phone of tenants who are married and paying rent > 9000 using subqueries.

How do I join on the link between tables?

```
select FIRST_NAME+ ' '+ LAST_NAME as FULL_NAME,PHONE,EMAIL
FROM PROFILES
WHERE PROFILE_ID IN
((
    SELECT PROFILE_ID
    FROM PROFILES
    WHERE MARITIAL_STATUS= 'Y' ) and
                (   SELECT PROFILE_ID
                    FROM TENANCY_HISTORIES
                    WHERE RENT> '9000'));
```

Comment: Post at least the structure of your tables. Also, why don't you use simpler left joins ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `and` in the list of ID's output for the `in` clause. Try as following:

```
select FIRST_NAME+ ' '+ LAST_NAME as FULL_NAME,PHONE,EMAIL
FROM PROFILES
WHERE 
(PROFILE_ID IN
(
    SELECT PROFILE_ID
    FROM PROFILES
    WHERE MARITIAL_STATUS= 'Y' ) or PROFILE_ID IN
                (   SELECT PROFILE_ID
                    FROM TENANCY_HISTORIES
                    WHERE RENT> '9000'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) as full_name, email_id, phone 
FROM dbo.Profiles
WHERE marital_status = 'Y' AND profile_id in (
SELECT profile_id 
FROM dbo.Tenancy_Histories
WHERE rent > 9000);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are poor. Please explain why/how this answers the question. Please read the edit help re block formats for code. Please before publishing look at the fomatted version of your post. [answer] [Help] This doesn't answer the question, which says to use subqueries.